# CScript when called as a process in c# only opens 32 bit version

Tags: c#, vbscript, process, 64-bit

I am running a VBS file that needs to be executed on the 64-bit version of cscript. On the command line, when I call cscript, it opens the 64-bit version located at `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe` and the VBS file works fine.

However, I'd like to call this VBS file through C# as a Process. Starting the process with the FileName as `cscript` does open cscript, but only opens the 32-bit version, located at `C:\Windows\SysWoW64\cscript.exe`.

Even when I set the FileName to specifically point to the 64-bit version of cscript, it only loads the 32-bit version.

How can I force the process to open the 64-bit version of cscript?

Here is my code, including the 64-bit version file path explained above:

```
string location = @"C:\location";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = location+@"\VBS\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "scriptName.vbs";
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements there is another solution.

Some background: When you run a 64-Bit application and try to start `cscript.exe` then you call `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe` (or more general `%windir%\System32\cscript.exe`)

However, when you run a 32-Bit application then each call to `%windir%\System32\` is automatically redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64\`. In this directory you will find all your 32-Bit DLL's. This redirection is done by Windows internally and your application does not recognize any difference.

In order to access `%windir%\System32\` from a 32-Bit application you can use `%windir%\Sysnative\`, i.e. `process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\cscript.exe";` should work even if you compile your application as 32-Bit.

Note, folder `%windir%\Sysnative\` does not exist in 64-Bit environment, thus you may check your run-environment by `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, so

```
if Environment.Is64BitProcess {
   process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe";
} else {
   process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\cscript.exe";
}
```

See also [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(VS.85))

Note, a similar mechanism exists also for the Registry, see [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Great, more concrete answer. Good to have on record as Visual Studio shuffles around their options with each release. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer has arose:

In my C# application I am creating, in Visual Studio (2017) had selected my `Platform target` to `Prefer 32-bit`, which should perhaps better be called as "force 32-bit".

By unselecting this option, my process ran as 64-bit, both by specifying the 64-bit path as the code above, but also by just running the cscript by name.

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript";
```

Toggle this option inside Properties > Build > Prefer 32-bit

Comment: You can select your own comment as answer so people don't keep looking to see if it's answered.