# System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PasswordValidator' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, oracle, iis

I need to refer ***several 32-bit dlls*** in my project. Basically, it contains several WCF services that connect to ***Oracle DB*** and do some CRUD operations. When I deploy my solution into IIS and set Application pool to

***Enable 32-bit Applications*** to ***False***, getting this exception...

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PasswordValidator' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
```

***Enable 32-bit Applications*** to ***True***, getting this exception...

```
The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

The connection string is:

```
Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source =lsdb; User ID =ls_Data; Password =oracle
```

I have installed ***64-bit Oracle client***, this is the ***problem***. When I install ***32-bit Oracle client***, the issue is ***resolved***. How to resolve this by having ***64-bit Oracle client***.

I tried to build the project by setting platform target to ***64-bit, any CPU, x86***. No use. If I set to 64, my DLL itself can't be loaded if I set Enable 32-bit to True (of course, expected behavior).

Comment: In a 32-bit application you have to use also the 32-bit Oracle Client, you cannot mix the architecture within a process. "AnyCPU" means 64-bit on nowadays 64-bit Windows, resp. 32-bit on old 32-bit Windows. You an install both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle Client on one machine, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Yes, we can install both on one machine. However, DBA at client side not allowing us to install the 32-bit client. Even though, I refer 32-bit DLL, Why can't I build the solution to 64-bit...

Comment: That's a core Windows limitation. A process can run only in one architecture. Consider to use the **ODP.NET Managed Driver** (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`), this is just a single DLL compiled on "AnyCPU", i.e. this one works on both, 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it's not working :(. Still, it is showing same behaviour i.e. PasswordValidator.dll missing...

Comment: Looks like you have two different problems. One miss file `PasswordValidator.dll` the other one miss the `OraOLEDB` provider. All comments above are related to the missing OraOLEDB provider only.

Comment: thank you. it worked out...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this,

set **Enable 32-bit Applications** for Apppool in IIS to **True**

uncheck **Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for websites and projects** setting available under **Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Projects**

[image: Use 64-bit version of IIS]

Use **ODP.NET Managed Driver (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client)** for Oracle DB connection **not OLEDB**.

Don't forget to compile by setting **Target Platform** to **Any CPU**

Thanks to Wernifried Domscheit

Comment: When you use the managed driver then it does not matter if you set 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: What about 32-bit dlls referred in solution. You mean I can compile my solution to 64-bit even if I refer 32-bit dlls?

Comment: It does not matter. The application loads automatically the 64-bit DLL (from `%windir%\System32`) or the 32-bit DLL (from `%windir%\SysWOW64`), this is called [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(VS.85)) See another example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855084/cscript-when-called-as-a-process-in-c-sharp-only-opens-32-bit-version/46935059#46935059